# Asp.Net Core SpaTemplate never can get Angular Material to work

Tags: angularjs, angular, asp.net-core

I have been trying for weeks to get Angular Material into the SpaTemplate from Microsoft. Can someone please help me understand why I simply cannot follow the startup guide for Angular Material and have it work? Can someone please help me get a project to the point that I can start to work with Angular Material from the SpaTemplate.

I have turned off server-side pre-rendering, because I am aware that causes problems. But aside from that I have tried installing Angular Material, I see some errors in the cmd. I import and add MaterialModule, then I see more errors talking about `'ng-template' is not a known element`. I have removed the UniversalModule from my imports array and that causes more problems.

Repo here if someone could please help. [Repo](https://github.com/HolyBreadstick/SpaTemplate-No-ServerSideRender)

Also am I the only developer who is coming from Angular 1.x and honestly not interested at all? Angular 1 was easy to develop in, the setup wasn't that hard, and adding outside code was as easy as copy and paste. Angular 2 feels like they made this really great framework and then no one knows how to use it when it comes to hosting it on a server.

Answer (score 0):

I started with the new template that was just released with core 2.  I have everything working except the table...not sure why yet on that one.

Tried priming and other, without success.  Closest on Material..just no tables yet and not sure I understand the datasource.

Hope this helps...still a newbie on this stuff.

Don't forget to manually rebuild webpack after you make changes.
webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js

webpack.vendor

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const treeShakableModules = [
    '@angular/animations',
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/forms',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router',
    '@angular/material',
    '@angular/cdk',
    'zone.js'


];
const nonTreeShakableModules = [
    'bootstrap',
    'hammerjs/hammer',
    "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
    'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
    'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
    'es6-promise',
    'es6-shim',
    'event-source-polyfill',
    'jquery',
];
const allModules = treeShakableModules.concat(nonTreeShakableModules);

module.exports = (env) => {
    const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('vendor.css');
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { modules: false },
        resolve: { extensions: [ '.js' ] },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg|gif|jpg)(\?|$)/, use: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }
            ]
        },
        output: {
            publicPath: 'dist/',
            filename: '[name].js',
            library: '[name]_[hash]'
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }), // Maps these identifiers to the jQuery package (because Bootstrap expects it to be a global variable)
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\@angular\b.*\b(bundles|linker)/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14898
            new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^vertx$/) // Workaround for https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise/issues/100
        ]
    };

    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        entry: {
            // To keep development builds fast, include all vendor dependencies in the vendor bundle.
            // But for production builds, leave the tree-shakable ones out so the AOT compiler can produce a smaller bundle.
            vendor: isDevBuild ? allModules : nonTreeShakableModules
        },
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist') },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, use: extractCSS.extract({ use: isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' }) }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            extractCSS,
            new webpack.DllPlugin({
                path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
                name: '[name]_[hash]'
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
        ])
    });

    const serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        target: 'node',
        resolve: { mainFields: ['main'] },
        entry: { vendor: allModules.concat(['aspnet-prerendering']) },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp', 'dist'),
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
        },
        module: {
            rules: [ { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, use: ['to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' ] } ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllPlugin({
                path: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
                name: '[name]_[hash]'
            })
        ]
    });

    return [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
}
```

I using the app.module.shared with the asp-rendering removed from index.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './components/fetchdata/fetchdata.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './components/counter/counter.component';
import { HttpTestComponent } from './components/Httptest/httptest.component';
import { MaterialTesterComponent } from './components/Httptest/materialTester.component';
import { MaterialGridComponent } from './components/Httptest/materialgrid.component';



import { MaintService } from './Services/maint.service';


import {
    MdButtonModule,
    MdChipsModule,
    MdProgressSpinnerModule,
    MdCardModule,
    MdDatepickerModule,
    MdInputModule,
    MdAutocompleteModule,
    MdNativeDateModule,
    MdCheckboxModule,
    MdRadioModule,
    MdSelectModule,
    MdSliderModule,
    MdSlideToggleModule,
    MdMenuModule,
    MdListModule,
    MdGridListModule,
    MdTabsModule,
    MdProgressBarModule,
    MdTableModule,
    MdCoreModule,
    MdExpansionModule,


} from '@angular/material';

import { CdkTableModule } from '@angular/cdk';


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        CounterComponent,
        FetchDataComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        HttpTestComponent,
        MaterialTesterComponent,
        MaterialGridComponent,

    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        CdkTableModule,
        MdButtonModule,
        MdChipsModule,
        MdProgressSpinnerModule,
        MdCardModule,
        MdInputModule,
        MdTabsModule,
        MdExpansionModule,
        MdDatepickerModule,
        MdNativeDateModule,
        MdCheckboxModule,
        MdRadioModule,
        MdListModule,
        MdCoreModule,
        MdProgressBarModule,
        MdSelectModule,
        MdSliderModule,
        MdSlideToggleModule,
        MdMenuModule,
        MdGridListModule,
        MdTableModule,
        MdAutocompleteModule,
          RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ])
    ],
    providers: [
        MaintService
    ]
})
export class AppModuleShared {
}
```